# Recurrence relation $f(n)=2f(n-1)+n\log(n)$

Tags: recurrence-relations

How to solve the following recurrence relation: $f(n)=2f(n-1)+n\log(n)$ ?
I tried to write $f(n-1)=2f(n-2)+(n-1)\log(n-1)$, so

$f(n)=4f(n-2)+2(n-1)\log(n-1)+n\log(n)$

and then the general relation at the $k$'s iteration level is complicated, is there another method to solve this?

Comment: $2^{-n}f(n)=f(0)+\sum_{k=1}^{n} 2^{-k}k\log k$

Answer (score 1):

If you continue to write it l, you get that

$f(n)=4f(n-2)+\log(n^n(n-1)^{2(n-1)})$

This suggest you that the general formula is

$f(n)=2^nf(0)+\log(\prod_{k=1}^n k^{2^{n-k}k})$

Check it using induction to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the equation by $2^{-n}$, and you will get
$$
2^{-n}f(n) = 2^{-(n-1)}f(n-1) + 2^{-n}n\log n.
$$
Then you can sum over this equation.